# mysql store procedure insert using two parameters

Tags: mysql

i am new to store procedure i am passing three string to procedure (table_name,fields_name,values) to insert data.

```
DELIMITER 

CREATE PROCEDURE insert_into(IN table_name VARCHAR(255),IN fields_name VARCHAR(255),IN valuess VARCHAR(255),)
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = CONCAT('insert into ',table_name,'(',fields_name,')values (',valuess,')');
        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
DELIMITER ;
```

Getting Error

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'table_name' in 'field list'
```

Comment: Show us the code you are using to create the stored procedure

Comment: How are you calling the procedure?

Comment: DELIMITER 
    CREATE PROCEDURE insert_into(IN table_name VARCHAR(255),IN     fields_name VARCHAR(255),IN valuess VARCHAR(255),)
BEGIN
     SET @sql = CONCAT('insert into ',table_name,'(',fields_name,')values    (',valuess,')');
 
     PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
     EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
 
    END
    DELIMITER ;

Comment: call insert_value("testing","`name`,`email`","'human','abc@abc.com'");

Comment: 1) Pls edit the question next time. 2) This can't be the full code because there are multiple syntax errors in the definition itself (delimiter not defined, a comma at the end of the  parameter list)

Comment: Why are you defining a stored procedure that creates a query? Just create the query. This thing is just asking for SQL injection problems. MySQL has a built-in insert function called `INSERT`.

Comment: i have create query before but thats also not working for me then i search from internet and change the code

Comment: Can you describe the initial problem you were trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

```
 DELIMITER $$
--
-- Procedures
--
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insert_value` (IN `table_name` VARCHAR(1000), IN `fields_name` TEXT, IN `valuess` TEXT)  
BEGIN
 SET @sql = CONCAT('insert into ',table_name,'(',fields_name,')values (',valuess,')');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  END$$

DELIMITER ;
```